# python, difference between import ssl and import _ssl

Tags: python, ssl, import

What is the difference between

```
import ssl
```

and

```
import _ssl
```

I am running python code on different servers. On some servers, both works for me. On other servers, only the second one works, the first one gives me the following:

```
ImportError: No module named ssl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different modules. _ssl is an internal support module for SSL operations where ssl is the actual module providing SSL services. "No module named ssl" means that on that server python was not compiled with SSL support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does this _ssl provides the almost same interface as the actual ssl module?
In other words, if the server python was not compiled with SSL support, can I import _ssl and achieve almost the same thing using _ssl instead of ssl?

Comment: No, you cannot. As I said, _ssl is a support module. It provides some SSL related utility functions, constants etc. but not the actual SSL implementation.